# Framing the future as the past for another future (tense)

Tags: participe-passé, futur

I want to say something like "After I have gone to university, I will go..."

Do I use the perfect past then future or another tense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can simply say:

> Après avoir terminé mes études, j'irai...

That is how you also preserve the English structure.

*Après que* is usually used when the subject in the main clause is different from that found in the subordinate one.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas in English we use the present perfect, in French you use the future perfect (*futur antérieur*). This is then matched with either of the normal future tenses.

**(Updated)** Here's that *concordance* in action in a sentence similar to yours:

> Quand j'aurai terminé mes études, je partirai en France.

Outside of "textbook speak", it may be possible to exchange the *futur antérieur* for another tense (perhaps the *futur simple* ?). I leave it to a native speaker to weigh in or submit their own answer.

---

**Alternatives**

I think you could use *après que* instead of *quand* ("after" vs. "when"), but Feelew suggests otherwise. If *quand* sounds more natural, it might be because *après que* is usually paired with a subjunctive, which isn't possible in a future tense. The meaning would be the same for either choice in the future perfect, so choose what sounds most natural.

Either way, it can be changed for *après* alone if the subject is the same in both halves of the sentence. If you do this, then the first tense is the perfect infinitive:

> Quand la pluie aura cessé, je... *(Subject changes)*
>   
> Après avoir terminé mes études, je... *(Subject is the same)*

It's also possible to use the *futur simple* for this first tense, but the meaning is slightly different, because it doesn't necessarily mean the action is finished.

> Quand la pluie cessera, je sortirai. *(The choice of verb implies that the action is over anyway)* 
>   
>  Quand j'étudierai le français... *(Alert! The future action would not be over yet)*

---

**Second tense**

Also, for some verbs you could combine a future with the infinitive for the second half of this structure. Compare these two versions:

> Après avoir terminé mes études, je vais travailler / je travaillerai.
>   
> Après avoir terminé mes études, j'irai travailler.

To me this seems to be mainly a difference in wording: "I will work" vs. "I will go to work."

Comment: Hum, I would say "Après que j'aurai terminé mes études, je travaillerai".

Comment: Voire « j'irai travailler »

Comment: When it comes to **saying**, I would definitely use _«je vais [aller] travailler»_, but true, the _futur simple_ is usually more elegant, simply not much used anymore (at least in Quebec). Also, it seems to me that although English "after" and "once" are about equivalent, I would select "Quand j'aurai" over "Après que j'aurai" in French.

Comment: @Toto Luke ne voulait pas dire "se rendre à son travail" mais "commencer un nouveau travail à la fin de ses études". Mais son exemple a disparu avec l'édition de son commentaire...

Comment: En tout cas, pouvoir les comparaître de façon plus proche me semble être le mieux. Je rajoute la première version...